# get document title with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have to get document title from ajax success data without regex . For example this is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/7UyRa/

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://somesite.com',
        success: function(source) {

            var title = $(source).attr('title');

            //or

            var title = $(source).find('title').text();

            console.log(title);
        }
    });
 });
```

It returns 'undefined'

Answer (score 3):

Your example violates the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In short, you can not request arbitrary domains using a `XMLHttpRequest` with Javascript.